# Timestamp (firebase) casting error to Date util

Tags: android, firebase

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at dragon.bakuman.iu.mymallapp.DBqueries$9.onComplete(DBqueries.java:584)

Line 584: (Date) documentSnapshot.get("validity")));

Note it is Firebase Timestamp to Date. I tried both ways, when substituting Timestamp to Data and Date to Timestamp, none is working.

Here is the code: https://github.com/iudragon/MyMallApp

Please select "loadingRewards" BRANCH on GITHUB

Here is the Firebase Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mM93.jpg

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the code into this

```
documentSnapshot.getTimestamp("validity").toDate();
```